# How to format cell in XWPFTable in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am able to create a table in Apache POI in word ,my table is coming with proper value but what i want i want to decrease the cell size of the  column  size in the table how to do that ,please help..Here is what i have done upto

```
              XWPFTable table = document.createTable(5,3);

        r3.setText("MSH Activity Score Card");
        r3.setBold(true);



        //creating first row 
        table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setText("Job ID#"); 
        table.getRow(0).getCell(2).setText("1362"); 

        //creating second row

        table.getRow(1).getCell(1).setText("Job Title#"); 
        table.getRow(1).getCell(2).setText("Global Network Architect Consultant");

        //creating third row
        table.getRow(2).getCell(1).setText("Client");
        table.getRow(2).getCell(2).setText("Carnival Corporation"); 

        //creating fourth row
        table.getRow(3).getCell(1).setText("Start Date");
        table.getRow(3).getCell(2).setText("11/13/2014");

       //creating fifth row
        table.getRow(4).getCell(1).setText("Days Old");
        table.getRow(4).getCell(2).setText("33");

        CTTblWidth width = table.getCTTbl().addNewTblPr().addNewTblW();

        width.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
        width.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1500));
```

I am getting a table with data but i want to minimize the size [image]

But i want this size[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to make sure that you've declared the library's imports :

```
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableCell;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableRow;
```

Then it's just like , assuming you want to format `cell-0` on `row-0`:

```
table.getRow(0).getCell(0).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2000));
```

Or put this snippet after creating your last row to format all cells:

```
for(int x = 0;x < table.getNumberOfRows(); x++){
          XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(x);
          int numberOfCell = row.getTableCells().size();
          for(int y = 0; y < numberOfCell ; y++){
              XWPFTableCell cell = row.getCell(y);

              cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2000));
          } 
        }
```

*But remember that the width of the cell will always increase to follow the length of the string.

Comment: where i should write that?? before the table starts?

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR.getDrawingList()Ljava/util/List;
 org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun.<init>(XWPFRun.java:99)
 org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph.createRun(XWPFParagraph.java:272)
 com.msh.servlet.GenerateDoc.doGet(GenerateDoc.java:170)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

Comment: @lucifer, see update above !, you put the code after create your fifth row (or last row).

Comment: i am getting error on int Cells = row.getTableCells().size(); line

Comment: The method getTableCells() is undefined for the type XWPFTableRow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67215/discussion-between-lucifer-and-fev).

Comment: see my lastest edit above ! if it still doesn't work then you need to use newest POI lib. , probably your library is missing some components.

Comment: i already downloaded it but it is not working then please give me  list of jar please!1

Comment: your solutions works but can you tell me how can i change the size of the text in the table??

Answer (score 6):

Upon creation of the table, the layout is set to "auto" by default hence the width of the cell will always increase to follow the length of the string. As per OpenXML markup, it look's like

`w:tblPr
w:tblLayout w:type="auto"`


the solution is to set the layout to **fixed** and set the individual column length

`w:tblPr
w:tblLayout w:type="fixed"`

Here's the poi code for setting table layout:

```
XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
CTTblLayoutType type = table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblLayout();
type.setType(STTblLayoutType.FIXED);
```

Here's how to set the individual width:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(i);
        int numCells = row.getTableCells().size();
        for (int j = 0; j < numCells; j++) {
            XWPFTableCell cell = row.getCell(j);
            CTTblWidth cellWidth = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();
            CTTcPr pr = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
            pr.addNewNoWrap();
            cellWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2880));
        }
    }
```

column length 2880 is measured in twentieths of a point (dxa) or 1/1440 inch which is equal to  **2 inches**.

Answer (score 2):

In my project i have struggled alot to set column width and i have 
          solved this issue by controlling data in cell.

```
   CTTblWidth width = table.getCTTbl().addNewTblPr().addNewTblW();
   width.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
   width.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(9072));
```

Comment: it sets the width of table instead of cells