# Trying to have fixed columns in XWPFTable, I get a 'cannot resolve symbol CTTblLayoutType

Tags: apache-poi

As described here : 
[How to format cell in XWPFTable in Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541560/how-to-format-cell-in-xwpftable-in-apache-poi/41258542#41258542)

I have tried to use the code

```
XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
CTTblLayoutType type = table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblLayout();
type.setType(STTblLayoutType.FIXED);
```

I order to have fixed Columns. But I get a cannot resove symbol 'CTTblLayoutType'

I think I have all required dependencies in my classpath :

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>${poi.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>${poi.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

(with poi.version = 3.16)

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you [read the POI FAQ and follow the instructions given there for your problem](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025)?

Comment: thank's. With your point I finally found how to do it : I added : '<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>'

Answer (score 0):

So I needed to add :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It would be better if you referenced the FAQ entry in your answer, so other people having the same problem can get the `why` too!